# Send-MailMessage: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Subject'

Tags: windows, powershell

This error appears when running the script below:

> Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Subject'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

The email still sends successfully and the subject appears correctly.

```
$dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lists\TodaysLists"
$SMTPServer = "192.168.1.111"
$Time = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')

$japan = @{            
    Name = 'Japan'
    From = "me@me.com
    To   = "you@me.com"
    Cc   = "him@me.com"
}

$ireland = @{            
    Name = 'Ireland'
    From = "me@me.com
    To   = "you@me.com"
    Cc   = "him@me.com"
}

$Regions = @()
$Regions += New-Object PSObject -Property $japan
$Regions += New-Object PSObject -Property $ireland

foreach ($Region in $Regions) {
    $Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($Region.Name)*" -Recurse
    $AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName
    $Subject = "$AttachmentName"
    $Body = "Please find attached the Report for $($Region.Name).

Produced @ $Time 

Regards,
John Doe
"
    Send-MailMessage -From $Region.From -To $Region.To -CC $Region.Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment.FullName
    $Attachment | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lists\oldLists"
}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but the `From` values of you hashtables are missing a closing double quote.

Comment: The code tries to send two emails, and you say "*the email sends correctly*" - simple answer is that one sends correctly and one fails...?

Comment: Might be worth adding `-Verbose` to `Send-MailMessage` to help with your fault finding.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that `$Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($Region.Name)*" -Recurse` is not returning any files for one or more of the regions, so `$Subject` ends up being `$null`.

You could either check for that state and perhaps throw a warning instead of attempting to send the mail, or another way to work around the error (and get an email sent but with a blank subject) would be to add some other (guaranteed) text to `$subject`. E.g:

```
$Subject = "$($Region.Name): $AttachmentName"
```

Although then I suspect it would complain about `-Attachments` being null.

To add a check/throw warning, you could do the following:

```
foreach ($Region in $Regions) {
    $Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($Region.Name)*" -Recurse

    If ($Attachment) {

        $AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName
        $Subject = "$AttachmentName"
        $Body = "Please find attached the Report for $($Region.Name).

    Produced @ $Time 

    Regards,
    John Doe
    "
        Send-MailMessage -From $Region.From -To $Region.To -CC $Region.Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment.FullName
        $Attachment | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lists\oldLists"
    } Else {
        Write-Warning "One or more files named $($Region.Name) were not found in $dir. Mail not sent."
    }
}
```